# How to keep only alphanumeric characters of a string?

Tags: python, regex

How to retain alphanumeric characters in string.

Regex

```
def process_text(text):
    """
    Remove special characters
    Keep Alpha numeric + Space

    """    
    pattern = r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]'         
    text = re.sub(pattern,' ',text)
    text = " ".join(text.split())
    return text
```

Sample string

```
RegExr was created by gskinner34 in the summer of 69 :-).
```

Expected Output

```
RegExr was created by gskinner34 in the summer of
```

Comment: There are no special chars in your string, `69.` is alphanumeric. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @SilvanoCerza what about dot?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<=^|\s)[^a-zA-Z\s]+(?=\s|$)', '', stri)`

Comment: @snr you're right, the dot is not alphanumeric but `69` still is, we might need other examples I think.

Comment: Accordig to your description, this should work: `re.sub(r"[^0-9a-zA-Z ]", "", text)`, not according to your example. So explain your problem

Comment: @SilvanoCerza Sorry, I have updated the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help :

```
def process_text(text):
    from string import ascii_letters  as al
    return ' '.join(i for i in text.split() if any(j for j in al if j in i))
s = 'RegExr was created by gskinner34 in the summer of 69.'
print(process_text(s))
```

**Output** :

```
'RegExr was created by gskinner34 in the summer of'
```